# How do I make pyspark and ML (no RDD) working with large csv?

Tags: python-3.x, pyspark

I'm working with a relatively large CSV file and trying to train a `pyspark.ml.classification.LogisticRegression` model with it. The code below works well if a sample file contains a few lines (about 200). However, if I run the same code with the actual relatively large file (6e6 lines) I have a socket write exception. I've googled it but I couldn't find some advice. Please help me with this Exception with the large file:

[image: PySpark socketWrite Exception due to Executor Error]

This is the code that gives the Exception:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.ml.linalg import Vectors
from pyspark.ml.evaluation import BinaryClassificationEvaluator as Evaluator
from pyspark.mllib.regression import LabeledPoint
from pyspark.ml.classification import LogisticRegression
import warnings

spark = SparkSession \
    .builder \
    .appName("Python Spark SQL basic example") \
    .config("spark.some.config.option", "some-value") \
    .getOrCreate()

warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')

def vectorizeData(data):
    return data.rdd.map(lambda r: [int(r[-1]), Vectors.dense(r[:-1])]).toDF(['label','features'])



in_file = "C:\\Users\\HCAOA911\\Desktop\\data\\small_sample.csv"

CV_data = spark.read.csv(in_file, header=True) 

CV_data = CV_data[['step','amount','oldbalanceOrg','newbalanceOrig',
                'oldbalanceDest','newbalanceDest','isFlaggedFraud', 'isFraud']]
training_data, testing_data = CV_data.randomSplit([0.8, 0.2])

xytrain = vectorizeData(training_data)

lr = LogisticRegression(regParam=0.01)
model = lr.fit(xytrain)

xytest = vectorizeData(testing_data)
predicted_train = model.transform(xytrain)
predicted_test = model.transform(xytest)
evaluator = Evaluator()

print("Train %s: %f" % (evaluator.getMetricName(), evaluator.evaluate(predicted_train)))
print("Test %s: %f" % (evaluator.getMetricName(), evaluator.evaluate(predicted_test)))
```

I'm working with

- spark-submit --master local[*] .py
- Python 3.6.4
- Pyspark 2.2.1
- Windows 7

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

I've solved the problem by using better representation for ML models:

https://github.com/iarroyof/dummy_fraud_detection/blob/master/fraud_pysparkML_test.py

In this example, I used the object `pyspark.ml.feature.VectorAssembler` within a function called `vectorizeData()`.